# Advanced Custom Fields - add optional checkbox in repeater field with default text

Tags: wordpress

Looking for help on an ACF repeater to add in 2 pre-populated fields that the user could click the check box or radio button to apply on front-end or dont show if not checked.

--

Creating a menu for a client like this [an example w/ all fields to visualize it]: (https://ibb.co/t2rq49K)

Repeater has 5 sub_fields as you can see in my PHP: https://ibb.co/q5KLT67

In my PHP i haven't applied logic to the  <sup>*or the gfm. Would like to add 2 sub_fields in the repeater field that would translate when the user adds a new menu item so the user can check a box to add the*</sup>  and/or the gfm. The fields should be SEPARATE sub_fields as some menu items have the  <sup>and the , some dont have them at all, and some have just one (either *</sup> or gfm

At this point, there are see 3 fields i've put in (menu item name, description and price) that work great, however there are two other OPTIONAL items that I would like to have default values for:

*
and

gym

Looking for guidance on how/what to add in the ACF settings under the repeater field (type of field, etc) AND the if/else statements needed for these 2 fields.

Ideally would love to keep my code and adjust it, but if you need to rewrite it' ll that's fine too.

Comment: Links are broken.  I'm not sure it the question is a good fit to this site... if this required to edit PHP code using a local editor then it's off-topic. It might be on-topic in [so] or in [wordpress.se].